# How to filter a queryset with a many many to field object in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am creating an app in which I can display user properties but the problem that I am facing is creating specific property categories.

For e.g If a user clicks Condour Apartment then only those properties should be displayed. I wanna know how we can display on those properties which are connected by that category title.

Here's the models.py for properties and category

```
class Category(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

   def __str__(self):
    return self.title


class Property(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length = 210,default = 'None')

   STATUS_CHOICES = (
   ('R','Rent'),
   ('S','Sale'),
    )

   status = models.CharField(max_length = 210,choices =    STATUS_CHOICES,default = 'None')

    price = models.IntegerField()

    area = models.CharField(max_length = 210,default = 'None')

   ROOM_CHOICES = (
     ('1','1'),
     ('2','2'),
     ('3','3'),
     ('4','4'),
     ('MORE','More'),
    )

    rooms = models.CharField(
      max_length = 210, 
      choices = ROOM_CHOICES,
      default = 'None')
   BATHROOM_CHOICES = (
      ('1','1'),
      ('2','2'),
      ('3','3'),
      ('4','4'),
    )
    bathroom = models.CharField(max_length = 210, choices = BATHROOM_CHOICES, default = 'None')
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 210, default = 'None')
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 210, default = 'None')
    code = models.CharField(max_length = 210, default = 'None')
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images',)
    info = models.TextField(max_length = 1000, default = 'None')
    parking = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    air = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    swimming = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    laundry = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    dealer_name = models.CharField(max_length = 210, default = 'None')
    dealer_email = models.EmailField(max_length = 210, default = 'abc@gmail.com')
    dealer_number = models.CharField(max_length = 210, default = 'Not mentioned')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'user')
    timpestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)


    def get_absolute_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
      return reverse('profile_details:property', kwargs={'pk':self.pk,})

    def __str__(self):
      return self.title
```

Here's my views.py for the category property list

```
def Properties_Category_List(request):
    category_count = get_category_count()

    most_recent = models.Property.objects.order_by('-timpestamp')[:2]

    # I want to filter the model by the category title it was connected with

    model = models.Property.objects.filter(category__title='Multi Family')

    paginator = Paginator(model,1)
    page_var = 'list'
    page = request.GET.get(page_var)

    try:
        paginated_queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        paginated_queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        paginated_queryset = paginator.page(page)

    index = paginated_queryset.number - 1 
    max_index = len(paginator.page_range)
    start_index = index - 3 if index >= 3 else 0
    end_index = index + 3 if index <= max_index - 3 else max_index
    page_range = list(paginator.page_range)[start_index:end_index]


    context = {
        "property":paginated_queryset,
        'page_var':page_var,
        'page_range':page_range,
        'most_recent':most_recent,
        'category_count':category_count
        }

    template_name = 'properties/properties_category_list.html'  
    return render(request,template_name,context)
```

Comment: Your query looks correct, but your code looks to have lots of little errors in it.  It has both tabs and spaces which will cause syntax errors in python, and you misspelled `timestamp`.  You may want to post a description of what the problem is with your code:  e.g., when I run this code, "I see a page with only one property on it, but I am expecting eighteen" or "I am seeing an error where . . ."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
category = Category.objects.get(title="Condour Apartment")
properties = Property.objects.filter(category=category)
```

**EDIT**

At a fairly generic level, something like this

in `category.html`

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <a href="{% url 'categories' category.id%}">{{ category.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

in `urls.py`

```
path('category/<int:pk>/`, views.category_list, name="categories")
```

in `views.py`

```
def category_list(request, pk=None):
    properties = Properties.objects.filter(category__id=int(pk))
    context = {
        'properties' : properties,
        'categories' : Category.objects.all()
    return render(request,'category.html',context)
```

Comment: This is less efficient than what the OP originally had of `Properties.objects.filter(category__title='Condour Apartment')`

Comment: but i want it to be filter from every category

Comment: So you pass the category wanted to the function and replace `Condour Apartment` this that

Comment: What do you mean, I don't understand. Can you write the answer